# Unsync bluetooth audio volume control

Tags: volume-control, bluetooth-audio

After Android 6.0.1 update controlling the volume on my phone which is connected to a bluetooth device controls the volume on the bluetooth device. Before, when I changed the volume on my phone, the volume on the device still had his own volume control.

I understand, that for ease of use the merging happened - probably people disliked that they had to control two devices instead of one.

However, this means I lost a LOT of control over the fine tuning of the volume. This is a disadvantage for cases when you want to play through a bluetooth speaker a soft ambient in a low volume to fall asleep to. Now the lowest point of volume is high. Even though you can move the volume around in a non-discrete manner, you can hear, that only around 10-15 discrete volume values are used.

Is there no workaround, app, custom root modification or something I could do to switch back to two volumes instead of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for Fine Volume Control V2.0 in Google play.  I installed it based on earlier comments and cannot believe how happy I am with it!

Comment: Yeah, I used this and it helped me, but then I changed my phone and the problem disappeared. Don't know why I forgot to mention the app here.

Comment: App is not free.

Answer (score 18):

Goto Developer Options, activate the "Disable Absolute Volume" toggle (see screenshot). Disconnect and reconnect your Bluetooth connection. Problem solved.

NOTE: This was done on Android 7.0. You can try on your own OS version.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: To enable developer mode, go to Settings-> About Phone  and tap the Build Number 7 times. https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-l/general/enabling-hidden-developer-options-t2548353

Comment: It also works on androud 8.1!! Also thanks, it solved my issue.

Comment: I had to disconnect and reconnect my headset, but then it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Android 9 on OnePlus allows this through Sound > Earphone mode > Bluetooth absolute volume.